# Multiselect With Quantity

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

[image]

[image]

I already searched around for similar multiselect boxes but i didn't found one with the option to input something along with your selection. Is this possible in a way or in a similar option. or does anyone have a different approach in laravel ? Also i have some questions on the server side how i gonna handle that in the request.

I hope one of you guys know a solution to my issue

Comment: https://select2.org/ maybe?

Comment: I can not find anything about it